# Instragram hashtag search

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram

Referring to the code on https://github.com/potomak/jquery-instagram

I am a novice at JavaScript and JQuery, cannot find where I should substitute the client ID, access token in the code or in which file. I can see the readme file has a 'getting started' which mentions the client id. But,if I save this file with all the other files, the webpage still shows 'no page found'.  I have generated the client info and access token info from the Instagram. 
Thank you for https://twitter.com/johnnyaboh for sharing the code.

Comment: You don´t need to replace or modify any file, just need to include their library, and with jquery also included do `$('.instagram').instagram({
    hash: 'love',
    clientId: 'YOUR-CLIENT-ID-HERE'
  });`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code at https://github.com/potomak/jquery-instagram/blob/gh-pages/index.html as a starting point, but remember to replace the client id used there with your own client id to avoid rate limit exceptions.

Comment: Thank you! the code seems relatively easy to understand. However, when I am replacing the client id with the one I acquired upon registration, the photos don't populate, it does populate using the client id in the code. I am wondering if there is some problem registering my client on Instagram. Do I need to go through any step in between obtaining the client id & secret and pasting it in the code? I think I might be missing a step with the client id.